# java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Schema for type MyClass is not supported

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am using Spark 1.5.0 and I have an issue while creating a dataframe from my rdd.

Here is the code:

```
case class MyC (myclass: MyClass) 

  val df = rdd.map {t => MyC(t)}.toDF("cust")
  df.show()
```

Here is the error message:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException:
>   Schema for type MyClass is not supported

Any help with this will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Spark uses reflection to infer dataframe schema, but cannot do so for arbitrary classes.  I'm not sure if I can state an answer better than the Spark docs can, and [there's a section dedicated to exactly this](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#inferring-the-schema-using-reflection).

To be specific, the problem is that there are a limited number of types for which Spark can infer schema.  Ints, Strings, Seqs/Arrays are all supported *(as well as case classes containing elements of these types)*, but an arbitrary class `MyClass` is not.