# Cast a DataFrame Entry to a Case Class with Any-type Member

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-dataset

I have a `DataFrame` with various types in the columns. For clarity's sake, let's say it is structured like below, with a column of `Ints`, a column of `Strings`, and a column of `Floats`.

```
+-------+-------+-------+
|column1|column2|column3|
+-------+-------+-------+
|      1|      a|    0.1|
|      2|      b|    0.2|
|      3|      c|    0.3|
+-------+-------+-------+
```

I was attempting to apply a UDF to all three of these columns to change each entry to a case class like that below:

```
case class Annotation(lastUpdate: String, value: Any)
```

By applying the below code:

```
val columns = df.columns
val myUDF= udf { in: Any => Annotation("dummy", in) }
val finalDF = columns.foldLeft(df){ (tempDF, colName) =>
    tempDF.withColumn(colName, myUDF(col(colName)))
}
```

Note that in this first pass, I don't care what the `Annotation.lastUpdate` value is. However, when attempting to run this,I receive the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Schema for type scala.Any is not supported
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$$anonfun$schemaFor$1.apply(ScalaReflection.scala:762)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$$anonfun$schemaFor$1.apply(ScalaReflection.scala:704)
    at scala.reflect.internal.tpe.TypeConstraints$UndoLog.undo(TypeConstraints.scala:56)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$class.cleanUpReflectionObjects(ScalaReflection.scala:809)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$.cleanUpReflectionObjects(ScalaReflection.scala:39)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$.schemaFor(ScalaReflection.scala:703)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$$anonfun$schemaFor$1$$anonfun$apply$6.apply(ScalaReflection.scala:758)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$$anonfun$schemaFor$1$$anonfun$apply$6.apply(ScalaReflection.scala:757)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:381)
```

I have been looking into custom encoders for resolving this issue, but am unsure of how to apply one in this scenario.

Comment: possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/40370735/1240268